# How to remove or replace the PyVista window icon?

Tags: python, pyvista

How can I remove or change the PyVista render window's icon? I have tried to search the issue also from the docs but didn't find any answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported directly in PyVista, but this is a great idea and I'll open a pull request to implement this [once a major refactor of render windows is done](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/pull/3216).

In the meantime you can use [raw VTK](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkWindow.html#a2d7a11da08501e60a37f7a78afd8fd44), the `SetIcon()` method on render windows. According to the docs this only works on Windows and Linux though.

As of PyVista 0.36.1 you have direct access to `plotter.ren_win` which is a VTK render window object. According to the docs the icon should be a `vtkImageData`; in practical PyVista terms this means `UniformGrid`s with dimensions `(n, m, 1)`.

Some experimentation suggests that the icon has to have uint8 active scalars of shape `(n_points, 3)` or `(n_points, 4)`, but I could only get the icon to actually show up on my linux machine with the latter setup. It seems that non-square shaped icons get tiled to square shape, so you have to crop your image to square shape first. Finally, you need to call `ren_win.Render()` before setting the icon, otherwise problems arise (on my linux machine: a segmentation fault).

Here's a small example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv
from pyvista import examples

# example icon: cropped puppy mesh turned from RGB to RGBA
icon = examples.download_puppy().extract_subset([0, 1199, 0, 1199, 0, 0])
data = np.empty((icon.n_points, 4), dtype=np.uint8)
data[:, :-1] = icon.point_data['JPEGImage']
data[:, -1] = 255  # pad with full opacity
icon.point_data['JPEGImage'] = data

# create a plotter with a dummy mesh and set its icon
plotter = pv.Plotter()
plotter.add_mesh(pv.Dodecahedron())
ren_win = plotter.ren_win  # render window
ren_win.Render()  # important against segfault
ren_win.SetIcon(icon)
plotter.show()
```

With this my bottom panel looks like this:

[image: panel item with icon that looks like the puppy image]

It also works for my window switcher:

[image: three large icons side by side, for gimp, "vtk" and firefox; middle one has the puppy image]

(Interestingly, the window title in the title bar is "PyVista" which is the default `title` in `pyvista.Plotter.__init__()`, but in the window switcher I see "Vtk". I don't know why this is but I'll also try to see if we can fix this.)

Opacity handling seems to work too:

```py
# add opacity in a nontrivial pattern
i, j = np.indices(icon.dimensions[:-1])
alpha = ((np.sin(2*i/icon.dimensions[0]*2*np.pi) * np.cos(j/icon.dimensions[1]*2*np.pi)) * 255).round().astype(np.uint8)
icon.point_data['JPEGImage'][:, -1] = alpha.ravel()
```

with this icon the window switcher looks like this:

[image: window switcher with three icons; "vtk" one has a funky black semitransparent overlay]

It looks funky but that's just because the opacity pattern itself is funky. Transparency shows up as the switcher's semitransparent background colour on my system.